# Android camera continuous focus stops working after Camera.autoFocus() call and can't be unlocked via Camera.cancelAutoFocus()

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, autofocus

I'm trying to implement touch-to-focus feature in my camera app.

Let's assume that camera always works `FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE` => which means I can use `Camera.autoFocus()` call to trigger manual auto focus.

Current logic is following:

1. `Camera.cancelAutoFocus()`
2. `Camera.Parameters.setFocusAreas(...)`
3. `Camera.autoFocus()`

Then simply wait for `Camera.AutoFocusCallback.onAutoFocus(...)`. This part works okay.

Later at some point I want camera to use continuous focus again. So I call `Camera.cancelAutoFocus()` and nothing happens. Focus is locked & camera doesn't attempt to focus automatically(continuously)

Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

Comment: How did you setup your `CameraParameters`?

Comment: What do you mean? Used Camera.getParameters(), modified it, then used Camera.setParameters()

Comment: Yes, any focus flags?

Comment: No change of focus flags. However, on startup focus mode is set to continuous picture